# How to iterate through file names and print out the corresponding file names with pathlib.glob()

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

`My Directory` looks like this:

```
P1_SAMPLE.csv
P5_SAMPLE.csv
P7_SAMPLE.csv
P10_SAMPLE.csv
```

How do I iterate through files in this directory using pathlib.glob() if I want to print out the corresponding file names?

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\My Directory'

for fle in Path(file_path).glob('P*_SAMPLE.csv'):
    print()  # What should the code here be?
```

I want my output to print this out:

```
P1_sam
P5_sam
P7_sam
P10_sam
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `print(fle)` or `print(file)`. Think you made a typo in fle.

Comment: Thanks @nauer. Yeah fle = file. But in the output I want `P1_sam` not `P1_SAMPLE`. How do I really just extract the number and print out the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\My Directory'

for fle in Path(file_path).glob('P*_SAMPLE.csv'):
    first = fle.name.split('_')[0]
    second = fle.name.split('_')[1]
    print("{}_{}".format(first, second[:3].lower()))
```

> Output :

```
P10_sam
P1_sam
P4_sam
P5_sam
```